# To pass model parameter using pagination in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pagination, pagedlist

I am using the PagedList to work on a table for my ASP.Net Core application. I need to pass the model to the controller on change of a page, however it's not being sent.

The pagination section of the code in the view is

```
<pager class="pager" list="@Model.UserList" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="User" asp-route-model ="@Model" param-page-number="page" options="@PagedListRenderOptions.ClassicPlusFirstAndLast" />
```

And my controller signature is :

```
public ActionResult Index(UsersModel model, int? page)
{
}
```

The model is always null and does not contain any of the model values. How do I fix it?

Comment: Which pagedlist package do you use?

Answer (score 2):

You could not pass the whole model object using `asp-route-{value}` or `asp-all-route-data`.

[asp-route](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers.anchortaghelper.route?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is for `string` type and [asp-all-route-data](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers.anchortaghelper.routevalues?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is for `IDictionary<string,string>` type

I suggest that you could pass model data manually like

```
@{
var parms = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Id",Model.Id.ToString() },
                {"Name",Model.Name },
                //...
            };
}

<a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="User" asp-all-route-data="parms">Test</a>
```

It will work as queryString.

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.0#asp-all-route-data

https://forums.asp.net/t/1984183.aspx?Passing+Model+Object+in+route+values+of+Action+link

Comment: Good answer! Also, if you need to pass an extra route parameter, do it after (not before!) the asp-all-route-data.  For example:  <a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="User" asp-all-route-data="parms" asp-route-sortOrder="organization">Test</a>